# Jquery click function not doing anything

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to get this click event working, so that when the user hits the button the alert is displayed. The end result, once I actually get the button working should expand the width of a div. However, whenever I click the button nothing happens. It won't display an alert, print - nothing. Any ideas?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                alert("Hello");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$("button")` will work perfectly. issue is some where else

Comment: can you write `html`  here?

Comment: If button is added after DOM is ready, then delegate event...

Comment: You should use `delegate event` biding if html is dynamically added to `DOM`

Comment: With WordPress use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: @Satpal Ya, or `$(document).ready(function($){...});` But now comes the silly question to OP: `Any error in console`???

Comment: @Satpal `$(document).ready(function($){...});` would work if set before `jQuery.noConflict()` is called

Comment: @A.Wolff, Now its complete info

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, "button" will only effect `<button>` tags.

Add id to button:  and then add # sign: $("#button").click. If this doesn't work I do have another solution...

Comment: This must be to real cause, However let OP confirm it. _Only answer which make sense_

Comment: Only have one button in at the moment. All others don't work either. I'm using WordPress if that makes a difference. First time ever touching JQuery, hence the noobiness

Comment: @HarryKitchener, With WordPress use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: What is the code for the button? Are you sure it is a <button> tag?

Comment: Yes, it's a button tag

Comment: Well, there are already a few answers that are the correct answers, mine was more or less just clarification for you.

Comment: Add id to button: <button id="mybuttonname"> and then add # sign: $("#button").click. If this doesn't work I do have another solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button1"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        });
    });
</script>
```